# the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'

Tags: ros, rosdep, sudo, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get this message when I SSH into Baxter, but I do not have sudo access so cannot fix this error message. Is there a way to remove this warning or run `rosdep init` without sudo? I tried and it says:

```
ERROR: cannot create /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d:
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ros'
Perhaps you need to run 'sudo rosdep init' instead
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194963/the-rosdep-view-is-empty:-call-%27sudo-rosdep-init%27-and-%27rosdep-update%27/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A sudo-less option for rosdep has been talked about for while now, but nothing has ever gotten rolled out.

This pull request addresses this by allowing you to set a `ROSDEP_PREFIX` which can be in your home folder or whatever:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/312

But there are substantial changes to the behavior of rosdep in that pull request and without more people pushing on testing it out and getting all the docs and tutorials updated, it won't make it into master.

We have addressed it in xylem, but that doesn't help you right now.

Currently there is no way to use rosdep without sudo that I know of, but you could manually modify rosdep's source code to install and look for those files in a different place, to which you can write. This isn't very sustainable because you would need to do this every time a new rosdep comes out, but it would work for now.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-10-15**:
Thanks for the details. As I just commented on that Github Issue, I think a sudo-less option is important, but I cannot get into working on that feature myself.